# ECS task hosted in one aws account can't connect to rds database hosted on another aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, aws-security-group

I am setting up an ECS Task on 1st aws account  that hold my app container which internally is connecting to the RDS database instance(hosted on another aws account) , I have made sure that the security group attached to the RDS database instance to allow all tcp traffic for testing. but whenever i launch a service based on the Task definition I created I receive the following error " *There was an error deploying ......  container. Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." (RequestToken: ..., HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException*)

this is a screenshot from the logs
[cloudwatch logs once creating the ECS Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOzqA.png)

I have tried to allow all the inbound traffic in the security group attached to the RDS instance but on Service Creation the same error appears "*There was an error deploying the .... container. Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." (RequestToken: ..., HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException*)
"
I was expecting that the service to get created normally and no connection error appear
Note I can connect to the database instance locally from mysql workbench so i assume that there should be no problem regarding connecting to the RDS DB instance

Comment: Does the ECS task have Internet connectivity? It either needs to have public IP assigned and be in a subnet with a route to an Internet Gateway, or it needs to be in a subnet with a route to a NAT Gateway.